# Locate ledger filename by block number in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I know the ledger consists of multiple files and each file has a maximum size limit(in my case), and all the blocks have been serialized and stored in these files.

I can query blocks info by block number but the file information is transparent to me(it should be). All the files are controlled by the `blockfileMgr` and the `checkpoint` only tracks the latest file.

Programmatically, is there a way to locate the file name by block number?

Comment: There are no built-in functions to do this.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GariSingh Actually, I found there is a method called `getBlockLocByBlockNum` in the `blockIndex.go` which can get the file suffix number.

Comment: That's an internal function though ... not part of the public API

Comment: That's true. I'm building a command line tool to process the ledgers data. Any suggestions for how to reuse this internal function? Extend `PeerLedger` interface is the way I'm trying to do currently. I tried to access the `index` db directly in previous but levelDB only allows a single thread at the same time.

Comment: Are you trying to build this as part of Fabric or is this just a tool for yourself?

Comment: It would behave just like other tools such as `cryptogen` or `configtxgen` as part of Fabric.